# Max Value displayed on matplotlib plot following navigation

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, max

I'm trying to return the maximum data value shown on a plot flowing navigation (e.g. pan or zoom).

Currently `ax.get_ylim()`, returns the max value of the y axis, and not the data displayed. Is this a bug within Matplotlib?

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague. Can you provide some code that you run?

Comment: data is not displayed probably because you did not call `matplotlib.pyplot.show()`

Comment: To do this will be significantly more invovled than using a single function

Comment: `ax.get_ylim()` will give the limits of the axes. You apparently want the maximum of the data. That is something completely different. So you need to get the data, filter it by the current limits, then calculate the maximum. Have you tried anything yet? What is the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried to filter the data by extracting the max & min values of the x axis (which is a datetime), and then interrogate the  corresponding range within the data plotted on the y axis. But 'xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()' is returning the  minimum and maximum datetime as '736435.541406' when it should be d/m/y h:m.

Comment: You may update your question with a [mcve] of what you have tried and a clear problem description of how it fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended function of ax.get_ylim(). Without this function (and get_xlim) doing what it does, there would be no way to get the max and min values displayed on the chart.

You can use the following to achieve what you want:

```
max(df[df["columninquestion"] < ax.get_ylim()[1]]["columninquestion"])
```